# Is it possible to count the number of shared characters in two cells / strings?

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

I have a large number of strings in a pair of columns in a spreadsheet. I'd like to write a formula to tell me whether "enough" initial characters of one cell are also initial characters of the *other* cell. Basically, I'm looking for something that can say "these two strings start with the same N characters" and then I get to choose what N I think means "enough" so I can flag the row using magic text, conditional-formatting or whatever.

Since the "choose the N" and magic text/conditional-formatting are well understood, I only need to figure out the "count shared characters" part so I'll focus on that.

For example:

| Column A | Column B | Formula Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Bar | 0 |
| Foo | Food | 3 |
| Foo | Fud | 1 |
| Bar | Bark | 3 |
| Bar | baz | 2 |
| Bar | abar | 0 |

What formula could be used to produce Column C from Columns A and B?

I can easily write a script/program outside of a spreadsheet to do this kind of thing, or maybe even a sufficiently complex SQL query if I load the data into a database first. But I'd like to deal with this at the spreadsheet level because (a) the data is already in a spreadsheet) and (b) this formula will be used by non-programmers once I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far I know, there is no quick way to achieve this. Please see the codes below for each cell:

```
=COUNTIF(B1,"*f*")+COUNTIF(B1,"*o*")+COUNTIF(B1,"*o*")
=COUNTIF(B2,"*f*")+COUNTIF(B2,"*o*")+COUNTIF(B2,"*o*")
=COUNTIF(B3,"*f*")+COUNTIF(B3,"*o*")+COUNTIF(B3,"*o*")
=COUNTIF(B4,"*b*")+COUNTIF(B4,"*a*")+COUNTIF(B4,"*r*")
=COUNTIF(B5,"*b*")+COUNTIF(B5,"*a*")+COUNTIF(B5,"*r*")
=COUNTIF(B6,"*b*")+COUNTIF(B6,"*a*")+COUNTIF(B6,"*r*")
```

---

###### Explanation:

- ###### `=COUNTIF` counts how many times something appears
- ###### `B1,` counts how many times it appears in cell B1
- ###### `*f*` counts how many times the letter "f" appears, even if it preceded or succeeded by other text

Comment: Yeah, I had considered a similar option: just copy/paste the same formula over and over with an increasing count-from-the-beginning like `IF(MID(B1, 0, 1) = MID(A1, 0, 1), 1, 0) + IF(MID(B1, 1, 1) = MID(A1, 1, 1), 1, 0) + ...` and stop after I have "enough" terms. If that's what's required, I might just do that.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't have been more helpful :(

Comment: Your formula counts letters found in the cell, but doesn't care about the position of those letters (right?). The position is important for me.

Comment: Yes; sorry, I didn't realise position is important